# Sending email through google mail in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I am trying to send email in codeigniter and this is a segment of code that i am using. The first commented code print error saying that my application does not have configuration to send email.

The second uncommented code which use gmail is working fine but it is a requirement to show my email and password. So I have two questions: How can I do what I want without mentioning my password. Is this acceptable in Software development to mention user password. Thanks

```
/*$config = array();
             $config['useragent']           = "CodeIgniter";
             $config['mailpath']            = "/usr/bin/sendmail"; // or "/usr/sbin/sendmail"
             $config['protocol']            = "mail";
             $config['smtp_host']           = "localhost";
             $config['smtp_port']           = "25";
             $config['mailtype'] = 'text';
             $config['charset']  = 'utf-8';
             $config['newline']  = "\r\n";
             $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
             */
   $config = Array(
        'protocol'  => 'smtp',
        'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
        'smtp_port' => '465',
        'smtp_user' => 'myemail@gmail.com',
        'smtp_pass' => 'mypass',
        'mailtype'  => 'text',
        'starttls'  => true,
        'newline'   => "\r\n"
        );

        $this->load->library('email',$config);

        $email=$this->input->post("email");
        $username=$this->input->post("username");
        $this->email->to("receiver1@gmail.com,receiver2@gmail.com,receiver3@yahoo.fr");
        $this->email->subject("Hello world");
        $this->email->subject("Hello world from local pc");
        $this->email->send();
        $data['msg']=$this->email->print_debugger();
```

Comment: You can create a new gmail account for that purpose :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You cannot send emails without using id and password in `smtp.googlemail`. The reason is simple. The smtp sends emails using your gmail account. So id and password are required. If you don't want to use your gmail account,you must have a mail server to send emails.

2) Coming to acceptability,using google smtp is fine when you don't have to share your files which contain confidential data like passwords.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had confusion since we are developing the project in a team and I can't find any way avoid making public for all developers we are working together.

Comment: @user1718215 If you are working in a company,it'll have some dummy email accounts exactly for this purpose. Create a new gmail account if you don't have them ..

Answer (score 0):

user1718215, the same question asked by me, so my solution is:

1) I failed when i used  mail or sendmail as protocol, you can try sendemail as protocol:

```
$config = array();
$config['mailpath']            = "/usr/bin/sendmail"; 
$config['protocol']            = "sendmail";
$config['mailtype'] = 'text';
$config['charset']  = 'utf-8';
$config['newline']  = "\r\n";
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
```

If it does not work, i suggest that you should use smtp as protocol, because there is no solution for failure of using mail or sendmail as protocol, maybe it's bug of php?

2)About your question.

> How can I do what I want without mentioning my password.

If you failed in using mail or sendmail, you can not do what you want without mentioning my password.

> Is this acceptable in Software development to mention user password.

It's acceptable to mention user password. Always, in this situation, people will create a new accout only for sending email, so don't worry about the security of your account.

3)Finally, good luck.

Comment: Thanks for making want confused me in the security. This means without mail server username and password are required.

Answer (score -1):

First code doesn't work because you have no E-mail server on your localhost...

First Configure **Mercury** or some other E-mail server on ur localhost.

You can use **Xampp** to install & configure all(Apache, Php, Mysql, Mercury, Tomcat etc) on ur local web-server

Second if you want to send email without username and password then it will go to **Junk/Trash E-mail** Folder of Recipent which is un-wanted so make dummy account on google and sent emails via that account

Comment: Please read the question properly. OP doesn't have problems with sending emails. He was asking about best practises